# How to edit image using WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to edit and download image in WordPress but my code not working. show this
[my script generate image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oTHK.png)

```
my code is 


$font = "https://demo.com/english/wp-content/themes/theme1/edit/font.otf";
    $date = "6-jun-2020";
    $date_font = "https://demo.com/english/wp-content/themes/theme1/edit/LFAX.TTF";
    $text = "Shyamol Singha";
    $img_src = "https://demo.com/english/wp-content/themes/theme1/edit/1.jpg";
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg('$img_src');
    $color = imagecolorallocate($img,105,105,105);
    imagettftext($img,40,0,160,250,$color,$font,$text);
    imagettftext($img,10,0,70,330,$color,$date_font,$date);
    imagejpeg($img,"it-edit.jpg");
    $edit_name = "it-edit";
    
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$edit_name.".jpg");
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    readfile("".$edit_name.".jpg");
    imagedestroy($img);
```